# Why won't browsers cache files output by PHP readfile()?

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

I am currently outputting some image files via PHP's readfile() using the following code but, I notice via Firefox and Chrome's dev tools that none of these files get cached.

```php
ob_start();
outputfile($fp);

function outputfile( $fp ) {

  header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fp));
  header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600");
  header("Etag: " . md5_file($fp));
  $date = gmdate("D, j M Y H:i:s", filemtime($fp))." GMT";
  header("Last-Modified: $date");

  readfile($fp);
  exit; // tried ob_end_flush() too before exiting

}
```

The code outputs the file with the following in the headers in the dev tools...

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2678400
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 155576
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 21 May 2018 22:31:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 19:34:05 GMT
Etag: 507f2520385c009a7385a1165032bd61
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
```

If I return control to Nginx to serve the file instead, it outputs the following headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 155576
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 21 May 2018 22:31:02 GMT
ETag: "5a9af8ad-4a5b"
Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 19:34:05 GMT
Server: nginx
```

Am I missing something that causes the browsers to not cache the image files?

I've tried adding all the necessary Cache-Control headers such as eTag and max-age but, the browsers just refuses to cache the data. I even tried copying all the headers from the server's output and using "ob_start('ob_gzhandler');" in case it was because the raw file data wasn't gzipped.

The browsers just won't cache any file data sent through PHP.

Comment: The least your script should support itself is [`If-Modified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since). Though it won't help much if Nginx overrides your response headers.

Comment: I've tried putting If-Modified-Since so that it's a later time than Last Modified in but doesn't seem to help. I thought eTag is supposed to take precedence anyway so that if the token hasn't changed then the browser will use its local cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem...

Was wondering if any cookie related code could affect readfile() and discovered that if I had session_start() before using the function, browsers will refuse to cache the file data sent. If I remove session_start() the browser caching works as expected respecting the Cache-Control headers sent.

I don't quite understand why this is the case since I compared the output of readfile() with and without session_start() before it and the output seems to be the same.

For the record I'm using PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

`Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT` **could** be the cause. Technically if the `Cache-Control` header has a `max-age` directive then `Expires` should be ignored (Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires). However it is worth checking by removing that header.

Your PHP code is not setting it. So I assume it is coming from some common config / code which gets executed on every outgoing response. Have you put this in your Nginx config for all PHP requests?

Comment: I had that thought too since the Expires date was in the past but after modifying it to be in the future the browser still refuses to cache it unfortunately.

Comment: @Ken How are you determining that the browser is not caching this image? In Firefox have you checked `about:cache` to see if this particular is actually cached or not?

Comment: Well, it should show "cached" under the "transferred" column in Firefox's Network Monitor" tab while in Chrome's dev tools, it will show "(from memory/cache)" under the Size column. Neither shows that status when I re-visit a page and examine the image files.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. But I ran into the same issue and this gave me a clue. My final solution that worked for me was to strip off all the headers that PHP normally sends, then replace them with my own that only relate to the file being sent.

I started with header_remove(); You may find that you don't need all these headers or maybe you need others. But these are what I am sending and I get the correct cache control.

I am sending thumbnail images that I build on the fly or pull from my own cache folder.

```
header_remove();
header('Cache-Control: max-age=' . Time::days(7));
header('content-disposition: inline; filename="thumb-' . $r["id"] . '-' . preg_replace('/\.[a-z]+$/', '.jpg', $r["name"]) . '"');
header('Last_Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", strtotime($r["modified"])) . ' GMT');
header("expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + Time::days(7)) . " GMT");
header('etag: "' . $r["etag"] . '"');
header("accept-ranges: bytes");
```